# Formula to distribute values among list

Tags: c#

In my application I am using below formula:

```
decimal retVal = this.selectedDetailVMItems.
    Sum(prod => prod.Product.NetPrice * prod.Product.ExtendedQty);
```

`NetPrice` is some thing like for example 457, 33, 40 etc..

Now I have to increase or decrease some value from `retVal`. When I do this, how do I distribute increased or decreased value in `prod => prod.Product.NetPrice`?

How do I handle this scenario?

Comment: elloborate your question

Comment: What do you mean "distribute"? You mean you want each element to share a % of the total increase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to uniformly distribute a value of

```
decimal distributeVal = TotValue / selectedDetailVMItems.Count();
```

then you can use a *Linq style* `Foreach` to distribute (with [+= Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx)) the above said value, taking into consideration also the `ExtendedQty`

```
selectedDetailVMItems.ToList().ForEach(prod => 
    prod.Product.NetPrice += distributeVal / prod.Product.ExtendedQty);
```